# Android app - Passing variables, setting spinner options

Tags: android, spinner

**Intro:**  I'm very new to Android/Java.  I'm taking a class for app development as it satisfies a requirement.  We receive no guidance when coding from the Professor/TA and I'm completely stuck.

**App:**  My app is REALLY simple.  Basically the first part is three spinner where you select your vehicle's year, make, and model.  The year is just for show.  Once you select the Make option, the model spinner should populate.  You then click next to go a new activity, I'd create one activity for each of the four vehicles that displays a fuel economy graph, image of the car, etc.

**Problem #1:**  Like I said, I want the "Model" spinner to popular from the "Make" spinner.  The Make spinner populates from my XML array, which is this:
***Make Spinner entries:***

```
           <string-array name="Make">
                <item >Select</item>
                <item id="Ford" >Ford</item>
                <item >Chevy</item>
            </string-array>
```

I am using code to try to populate the Model spinner, but it isn't working.  See below that code and some other details:

Main Java Class name:  Main.java
Class to popuplate "Model" spinner:  SpinnerPopulate.java

***XML Files:***
main.xml, strings.xml, content_main.xml

***Here's the Java I'm using that's inside of SpinnerPopulate.java***

```
            package edu.name.projectapp;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
            import android.widget.Spinner;
            import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
            import android.widget.Toast;
            /**
             * Created by All Users on 12/12/2015.
             */

            public class SpinnerPopulate extends Activity implements
                    OnItemSelectedListener{
                Spinner s1,s2;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerMake);
                    s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerModel);
                    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                }
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                           long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
                    Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(sp1.contentEquals("Ford")) {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add("Focus");
                        list.add("Mustang");
                        list.add("Taurus");
                        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                    }
                    if(sp1.contentEquals("Chevy")) {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add("Corvette");
                        list.add("Lumina");
                        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
                    }

                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }
```

The above code doesn't work and I can't figure out why.  I've tried switching the "extends Activity" to "extends Main", but it doesn't help.  My spinner id's are correct.  I just don't get it.

**Second problem:**
Once a person has made their selections, they click "Next".  That button uses the spinner selections to route them to a new activity.  So if you select Ford for the make and Taurus for the Model, you'll go to the FordTaurus activity.  What I don't know is how to do that.  I also need to pass their model year selection to this activity.  So if 2011 is selected, I can display at the top of the new activity screen.  I've tried a whole bunch of different code I found here and elsewhere, but haven't made it work yet.

Any help should be greatly appreciated, and I'm happy to provide more code, info, screenshots, whatever you may need to assist.

See below a screen shot of my main screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vQrd.jpg)

Comment: Could you please define what exactly isn't working for your first problem? From a quick glance at your code I see a few things that could be done better and simplified a little, but nothing immediately stands out as wrong. Once I get home I will take a proper look at your code and explain how you can show a new `Activity` with details about the vehicles.

Comment: @XaverKapeller  Thanks for looking man!  Yah, so basically when Ford is selected in the first spinner I'm trying to load three models of Ford in the second spinner.  Or when Chevy is selected, the Chevy Models.  But when I run the app, the Model spinner doesn't populate based on my Make spinner selections . . . and I don't know why . . .